# What can be used instead of If-else statement in this code?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
public static Currency getByCurrencyCode(String pCurrencyCode){

    if (CURRENCY_CODE_USD.equalsIgnoreCase(pCurrencyCode)){    
        return US_DOLLAR;    
    }    

    if (CURRENCY_CODE_HKD.equalsIgnoreCase(pCurrencyCode)){    
        return HK_DOLLAR;    
    }   

    if (CURRENCY_CODE_MYR.equalsIgnoreCase(pCurrencyCode)){    
        return MALAYSIAN_RINGGIT;    
    } 

    return null;    
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Comment: You could try to use enum or switch

Comment: can you explain one loop of this question with example sir.

Answer (score 1):

You could populate a `Map<String, Currency>` and return the `Currency` based on the name (and make the name consistently uppercase or lowercase). Something like,

```
private static Map<String, Currency> map = new HashMap<>();
static {
    map.put(CURRENCY_CODE_USD.toLowerCase(), US_DOLLAR);
    map.put(CURRENCY_CODE_HKD.toLowerCase(), HK_DOLLAR);
    map.put(CURRENCY_CODE_MYR.toLowerCase(), MALAYSIAN_RINGGIT);
}

public static Currency getByCurrencyCode(String pCurrencyCode) {
    return map.get(pCurrencyCode.toLowerCase());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of alternatives you could use. One is a `switch` statement:

```
public static Currency getByCurrencyCode(String pCurrencyCode) {
    switch (pCurrencyCode.toLowerCase()) {
        case CURRENCY_CODE_USD:
            return US_DOLLAR;
        case CURRENCY_CODE_HKD:
            return HK_DOLLAR;
        case CURRENCY_CODE_MYR:
            return MALAYSIAN_RINGGIT;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

However, that requires that the various `CURRENCY_*` variables be compile-time `String` constants and that `pCurrencyCode` cannot be `null`. I've assumed that the `CURRENCY_*` variables are all lower-case, but if they are upper case, just use `pCurrencyCode.toUpperCase()` instead.

Another approach is to define a map from `String` to `Currency` objects and look up the answer directly:

```
private static Map<String, Currency> sCurrencyMap;
static {
    sCurrencyMap = new HashMap<>();
    sCurrencyMap.put(CURRENCY_CODE_USD, US_DOLLAR);
    sCurrencyMap.put(CURRENCY_CODE_HKD, HK_DOLLAR);
    sCurrencyMap.put(CURRENCY_CODE_MYR, MALAYSIAN_RINGGIT);
}

public static Currency getByCurrencyCode(String pCurrencyCode) {
    return sCurrencyMap.get(pCurrencyCode.toLowerCase());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a map to hold these currency_code->currency? If used, you can simply use the CurrencyMap.get(currency_code) to replace all these if-else.